# Symfony forms: wrong error mapping for embedded form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, silex

I'm using Symfony2 forms with silex..

I create my form like this:

```
$form = $app->form()
    ->add('foo', new FooType())
    // ->add(...)
    ->add('save', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```

FooType:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class FooType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('bar', 'text', ['constraints' => new Assert\NotBlank()]);
        $builder->add('baz', 'text', ['required' => false]);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

If the "bar" field is empty the error always is mapped to the "foo" base field. Why? And how can I map the error to the field itself ("bar")?

Edit:

The form is rendered like this (Twig):

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Result after submit with empty fields:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label class="required">Foo</label>
        <ul>
            <li>This value should not be blank.</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="form_foo">
            <div>
                <label for="form_foo_bar" class="required">Bar</label>
                <input type="text" id="form_foo_bar" name="form[foo][bar]" required="required">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="form_foo_baz">Baz</label>
                <input type="text" id="form_foo_baz" name="form[foo][baz]">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="form_save" name="form[save]">Save</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="faebf2a0b0a05ddb8e5f40d58c7a3bf3d49522d4">
</form>
```

Comment: could you show us how the form is rendered?

Comment: I've updated my first post.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `setDefaultOptions` function? `error_bubbling` is `false` (default) and you shouldn't need that passage. I'm not sure this will resolve your problem but from the code you're showing us, render act like `error_bubbling` is setted to true :|

Comment: For compound forms `error_bubbling` is `true` by default: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-bubbling

So after removing `setDefaultOptions` the error message is bubbled on top of the form (instead of the top of `foo` field)..

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I didn't noticed "compund" word (to be true in italian the documentation don't say that :O)